# Qual padrão de response numa api rest quando executa parcialmente uma ação?

Tags: api, rest

`#define API http://localhost:80/api/v1/resources.`
 Ao fazer um POST em `resources`, o usuário(dev) pode registrar/incluir um N número de resources.
 Supondo que algum(uns) registro não pôde ser inserido, mas o restante foi com sucesso. Como poderia ser o response? Qual status? 200 ok, 201, outro? Qual padrão deve-se seguir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em situações similares eu utilizo o seguinte padrão:

- **`200`**`: OK`
  Nenhum erro encontrado.
- **`202`**`: Accepted`
  Sucesso ao enviar o payload. não é considerado um status de erro; retorne um payload contendo os descritores individuais de sucesso ou erro.
- **`40*`**`: Bad Request / Unauthorized / Forbidden / Not Found / etc.`
  Erros de validação.
- **`500`**`: Internal Server Error`
  A aplicação lançou uma exceção.
- Opcional - **`207`**`: Multi-Status` ([WebDAV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918))
  Se seu cliente suporta WebDAV ou XML, responda com um [payload multi-status](http://blog.terrydai.com/http-status-207-multi-status/), indicando os resultados de cada operação. A RFC que define 207/Multi-Status estabelece XML como formato desejado, o que pode evitar sua implementação em clientes baseados em REST/Json.

Comment: Talvez assim: http://pastebin.com/h1yeCq7w

Comment: @DanielVieiraJunior Sim, este padrão atenderia. Se desejar pode até incluir uma coleção com os registros corretamente comitados (dependendo das suas necessidades.)